# A limit with $x^{x^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

We need to find $$\lim_{ x\to 1^+}\frac{x^{x^x}-x^x}{x-1}$$
It seems to be not so hard to find , but I get stuck on this . Implicit I can find $\lim_{ x\to 1^+}x^{x^x}$ and  $\lim_{ x\to 1^+}x^{x}$. also I think I can solve it by L'Hpoital . my question :Is it possible to find this limit with out using l'hopital rule ?

Answer (score 3):

Taking $x^{x} $ as a factor in numerator we can see that the limit in question is equal to $$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\frac{x^{x^{x}-x}-1}{x-1}$$ and this can be further expressed as $$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}\frac{\exp((x^{x}-x)\log x) - 1}{(x^{x}-x)\log x} \cdot(x^{x} - x) \cdot\frac{\log x} {x-1}$$ and the desired limit is clearly equal to $1\cdot 0\cdot 1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\displaystyle x^x=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac 12 (x-1)^3+ o((x-1)^3)$

and $\displaystyle x^{x^x}=1+(x-1)+(x-1)^2+\frac 32 (x-1)^3+ o((x-1)^3)$,

$$\frac{x^{x^x}-x^x}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)^3+o((x-1)^3)}{x-1}=(x-1)^2+o((x-1)^2)$$

The limit is $0$.

Comment: The Taylor series for these functions around $1$ are not so common. This requires at least third order derivatives which is messy as well as totally unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. To evaluate the Taylor serie ( in particular, its second term), we need the derivative at the point. If we know the derivative (1 and 1, in this case), we can apply directly L'Hopital and say that lim=1-1/1=0. Moreover, calculus of the derivative from definition is a limit even worst than the original question. Is this answer not a logic loop? Or there are any other way of calculate these Taylor series?

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/taking-derivatives-calc/logarithmic-differentiation-calc/v/calculus-derivative-of-x-x-x) very nice video you will see that:

$$ \frac{ d }{dx} x^x = x^x ( \ln x + 1 ) $$

and

$$ \frac{ d }{dx} x^{x^x} = x^{x^x} ~ ( ~ x^x (1+\ln x)\ln x + x^{x-1} ~ ) $$

thus, using L'Hopital, the limit is (1-1)/1 = 0.

Comment: If you know the derivatives then why use L'Hospital's Rule. Just subtract and add $1$ in numerator and get the answer as $f'(1)-g'(1)$ where $f(x) =x^{x^{x}}, g(x) =x^{x} $. It is better to directly evaluate limit using limit theorems rather than calculating two derivatives using logarithmic differentiation.